# how to install qt5 in debian 11 stable?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, qt, qt5

I'm trying to play an NES emulator named punes, and on its github page, it says I need to configure and build manually. When I do `./configure`, I get `configure: error: Qt5 library not found`. However, when I do `apt list *qt5*`, it gives me an extremely long list of packages, none of which is an obvious `qt5` or `qt5-dev` package or anything like that, so it is completely non-obvious which one I need in order to "get qt5".

I'm on Debian 11 bullseye stable.

Answer (score 15):

I was able to solve this by doing `sudo apt install qtbase5-dev`, then `./configure` worked. It was completely non-obvious that the package name would be `qtbase5-dev`, since there's absolutely no way I could've known, short of Google searching for more than 30 min, that the package substring had `base` in between `qt` and `5`.